# Monotone map on a Preset

Tags: category-theory

Related to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348434/monoids-in-category-theory) I ran across this in the same book and thought I would try to get some clarity.

If $R$ and $S$ are both Presets with relation $\le$ then the function $f$ is a **monotone map** from $R$ to $S$ ($R \xrightarrow{f} S$) if:

$$\forall x,y \in R: \ x \le y \implies f(x) \le f(y)$$

This is all well and good, but obviously the first $\le$ is on the $R$ Preset and the second $\le$ is on the $S$ Preset.  Does this definition have *any* implication on the *meaning* of the two relations $\le_R$ and $\le_S$?  Do they have to be the 'same' relation (whatever that may mean)?

My guess is that it has no such implication but that leaves me wondering what practical use this really has since it would seem to come down to how clever you are at defining your relations in the two sets.

Comment: Are you writing this on a mobile phone? What seems like it should be "poset" is coming out "preset".

Comment: @MattSamuel no, according to the book I am going through R and S are presets

Comment: I see, it's a preordered set. I've never thought to abbreviate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can be different in nature:
 Consider e.g. the identity map for $f$ from $R=(\Bbb N,\,|\,)$ to $S=(\Bbb N,\le)$.

Comment: Thanks.  I still don't see what the monotone map buys you but perhaps I will after reading some more..

Comment: That's the '*structure preserving mapping*' between preordered sets (or posets).

Comment: the book I am using uses the term 'poset' to refer to partial ordered sets.  Probably to keep things confusing.  :)

Answer (score 2):

In mathematics, when you study sets with some extra structure/operation (for ex. multiplication in groups), you are also interested in studying functions that "respect" that structure (for ex. group-homomorphisms). With presets (also known as prosets=PRe-Ordered SETS) the structure/operation is the pre-order $\le$.
So with groups you are interested in functions $f$ such that:

$$\forall x,y \in G: f (x * y) = f(x) * f(y)$$

and with presets you study functions $f:R \to S$ such that

$$\forall x,y \in R: \ x \le_R y \implies f(x) \le_S f(y)$$

Do you see the similitude?

In a short while you will read that presets are a very "skinny" or "thin" kind of category and that monotone functions are functors and things will be even clearer.
At that point you will interpret $R$ and $S$ as thin categories and $\le_R$ and $\le_S$ as arrows in the respective categories. The monotone function $f:R \to S$ will be interpreted as a functor and you will be able to literally write:

$$\forall x,y \in R: f( x \le_R y) = f(x) \le_S f(y)$$

thereby fully mimicking the algebraic (for ex. group theoretic) formula given above.

Comment: This is pretty interesting.  I have a little trouble,  still, trying to come up with a concrete example I can relate to, but I think I follow the concepts well enough.  Trying to apply it will take some effort,  though.